# Ajax of opencart 1.5 not working after migration to development server

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, opencart

To replace this domain name "**example.ae**" with the development server name and its subfolder "**art.caps/examples**" (http://art.caps/examples)

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.ae$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.ae/$1 [R=301,L]

I tried to rewrite this, but it seems to be wrong. Anyone please help me to correct this with the development server path.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).art.capital

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://art.caps/examples/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

Ajax of opencart not working due to incorrect url rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

This rewrite issue can be solved by rename your htaccess.txt to .htaccess file and edit single line of code.

Replace this *RewriteBase /*

with  *RewriteBase /examples*